# Is PPTPD faster than Hamachi

Tags: linux, vpn, pptp

I encounter some issues with Hamachi. I want to set up any steamCMD server in my local network. The problem is my ISP doesn't sell public IPs and I simply can't forward port into my pc. I used hamachi but my friends complain about high ping (arround 120-150). When I'm playing on my friend server (which is in the same hamachi network) I also have such latency. Recenly I got OCI free tier instace. So when I setup pptpd server and invite my friends into it are there any chances that ping get any lower? I don't want to use OpenVPN or StrongSwan beacuse it requries installing third party app.

Comment: You do realize that Hamachi is third-party software, right, from a company that has had poor policies dealing with customer data and has had numerous security data leaking incidents.

Comment: I do. And that's why I don't want to install any other software and use Windows build in vps client to connect.

Comment: You can’t solve your question without additional software solutions. OpenVPN is one way, running a proxy is one way, both requires installing additional software

Answer (score 1):

> Recenly I got OCI free tier instace. So when I setup pptpd server and invite my friends into it are there any chances that ping get any lower?

Depends on how far you (and your friends) are from the instance. In most cases the latency will be *a little* higher than a direct connection (though it can be lower in some situations), but it's highly situation dependent. Ping your VM from a terminal, have your friends ping your VM too, add up the numbers to see what you should expect.

The CPU processing power of the server *might* have some influence when it comes to packet forwarding; if you're using Oracle OCI, consider using an (also free) Ampere ARM instance instead of the x86 ones.

> I don't want to use OpenVPN or StrongSwan beacuse it requries installing third party app.

If that's your only concern – Windows 10 has built-in support for IKEv2 as a VPN protocol (with strongSwan as the server).

(Also, don't confuse third-party apps with third-party servers. OpenVPN is a third-party app but does not use any "cloud" servers.)

However, this doesn't matter for latency; the protocol doesn't affect that, only the server's location does.